# Clear Contents of Cell Range Depending on Background Color

Tags: vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have conditional formatting which makes cells gray if they are inapplicable and green if they apply.

Can I apply "clear contents" to a range of cells if they are grey?

Much appreciated

Comment: What is the logic for the conditional format to format them grey in the first place?  You could use that same logic to find the cells and then perform a `ClearContents`.  Alternately, you could change the conditional formatting to have no fill but a custom cell format of `;;;` so that the cells appear blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the code below to all the cells in the given range:

```
Dim targetIndex As Integer
targetIndex = 16 'one grey
If (ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = targetIndex) Then
   ActiveCell.ClearContents
End If
```

You have to determine what you consider "grey". You might even include different indices just to make sure. Here you have a [useful link](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) with the indices associated with all the colours.